# Ansible - ec2_eni reuse ENI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have a pretty basic ansible playbook that creates an ENI:

```
---
- name: create ENIs
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
     - name: create eni 1
       ec2_eni:
         subnet_id: subnet-xxxxxxx
         region: us-east-1
         description: my-eni
         state: present
```

What i am trying to do is when i rerun this playbook, it does not create the new ENI but verifies that the ENI that was created and exists.

I cannot pass `Private IP` address as I want to reuse it across multiple accounts we have.

Is it possible to do so?

This is the ENI Module I am using:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_eni_module.html

Comment: Do you want to create a new ENI every time you run this?

Comment: No. Thats what it is doing right now and i want to avoid that.

Comment: Then how does ansible know whether to create a ENI or not? Unless you pass a private ip, there is no way to know whether to create or skip.

Comment: Can I grab the ip from output and use it as a variable? When it runs first time it sees that variable is empty so it goes and creates eni and reuses that on subsequent runs.

Comment: Yes. Register the result and save the IP. Then you can pass the IP so that it won't create again.

Comment: I am new to ansible. Do you have any pointers for me on how to achieve this?

Comment: Use `ec2_eni_facts` to check if the interface exists (Use description filter) and create a ENI only if the interface does not exists. I can help you later.

Comment: Does your ENI description change? Is it unique or can you make it unique?

Comment: Yes. It is unique.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Comment: Yes. It did. I appreciate your help. I am trying to do more now that I have good pinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ENI description is unique (very important assumption):

```
  tasks:
  - ec2_eni_facts:
      region: us-east-1
      filters:
        description: my-eni
    register: eni_facts

  - name: create eni 1 if not presemt
    ec2_eni:
      subnet_id: subnet-xxxxxxx
      region: us-east-1
      description: my-eni
      state: present
    when: not eni_facts.interfaces
```